# Having trouble using cookies, remember me works but cookies do not expire when unticked

Tags: php, html, session, cookies

never implemented cookies before, and I'm having some trouble. If the user checks the 'remember me' box and logs in, closes the browser, then re-opens it, they stay signed in, as they should. But if the user unchecks the 'remember me' box, logins in, closes the browser, and then reopens it, it is still signed in. I've tried everything I can think of!

```
<?php
  define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
  require 'connection.php';
  session_name('ppLogin');
  session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
  session_start();

  if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['ppRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
  {
  $_SESSION = array();
  session_destroy();
  }

  if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
  {
  $_SESSION = array();
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
  }

  if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
  {
  $err = array();

  if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
    $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

  if(!count($err))
  {
    $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM client WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password='".$_POST['password']."'"));

    if($row['username'])
    {
        $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        setcookie('ppRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);

    } else {
        $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }
}

if($err){
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
} else {
    echo "sent";
}
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/login.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate-login.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="menus">
            <div id="account">
                <a href="register.php" class="ui-corner-all"> REGISTER </a>
                <a href="login.php" class="ui-corner-all"> LOG IN </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navigation-menu">
                <a href="register.php" class="ui-corner-all"> CONTACT US </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if(!$_SESSION['id']):
        ?>
 <div id="login">
 <form id="login-form" action="do-login.php" style="autocomplete:off" method="post">
 <div id="form-part-1" class="l-form">
 <h1>Account details</h1>
 <p>Please enter your username and password in the boxes provided below</p>
 <label for="username">Username
 <span class="small"><label id="error_1"></label></span>
 </label>
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength='15'/>
 <label for="password">Password
 <span class="small"><label id="error_2"></label></span>
 </label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength='15' />
 <label for ="rememberMe">&nbsp;Remember me</label>
 <input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> 
 <div class="button" style="float:right;">
 <input value="Login" type="submit" name="submit" id="button_1" />
 </div>
 <div class="spacer"></div>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
        <?php
    else:
    ?>
<div id="already-logged-in">
<h1>You are already logged into your account</h1>
<h2>To go to your account: <a href="my-account.php" class="ui-corner-all"> My Account </a></h2>
<h3>Or log out: <a href="destroy.php" class="ui-corner-all"> Log out of My Account </a></h3>
</div>
        <?php
    endif;
    ?>
        <div id = "footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can mark the question as answered if it helps you. :)

Comment: I've still not sorted out the problem :(

Answer (score 3):

When a user logs in first time a cookie is created and saved with the expiry date. this will not delete or unset before expiry date unless you write some code to delete it. if the user unselect the checkbox i am probably guessing you are not deleting the cookie resulting in script retrieving the existing cookie. if you want to unset the cookie then upon unchecking you will have to set the cookie value to negative so that existing cookie is destroyed.